# How to decode base64 string to file without store it

Tags: android, file

I want to decode base64 string to file object to show it in my application without store it in disk.
 
the following code convert my string to file object but store it in local disk, How to avoid that?

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    if (base64ImageData != null) {
       fos = context.openFileOutput("imageName.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(base64ImageData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
       fos.write(decodedString);                        
       fos.flush();
       fos.close();             
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        fos = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So don't write byte array to file output stream. File object is representation of a file in a file system. You should convert byte array to Bitmap, not to a File if you want to keep it just in memory

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `fos.write`. Display `decodedString` using a method of your choosing.